# Multiple Azure Automation Accounts on a single Hybrid Runbook Worker

Tags: powershell, azure-automation

Is there any way to configure multiple Azure Automation Accounts on a single Hybrid Runbook Worker? Haven't tried it yet, figured somebody might know. Afraid I could mess up my installation while trying.

Answer (score 2):

I did try it after all and it's not working. When attempting to register another Azure Automation account, `Add-HybridRunbookWorker` will complain that there is already an account registered.